# Mysldump bash retrieve password form csv file

Tags: mysql, bash, sh

I'm creating a script bash to backup all my databases, so i created a csv file with all the databases confs like that : HOST;DB;USER;PASSWORD

```
 #!/bin/bash
Today=$(date "+%a")
export IFS=";"
DATE=$(date "+%Y%m%d")  
cat DB.csv | while read HOST DB USER PASSWORD; 
do 
    FILE="../../backupDB/$DB-$DATE.sql.gz"
    PASSWORD="${PASSWORD@Q}"
    echo $PASSWORD
    mysqldump --no-tablespaces --host=$HOST --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD $DB | gzip > $FILE
done
```

I got a problem with the password escaping.
I know that for mysqldump, to escape the password we need to put it into '' like that : --password='mypaswword!F*'

But if i retrieve it from a variable, it doesn't work : --password=$PASSWORD, i tried so many option that i prefer ask question because i'm newbie in bash script.

Regards

Comment: I don't see why a simple `--password="$PASSWORD"` would not work. By the way, you should do the same for other variables, including the `echo "$PASSWORD"` line.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice the PASSWORD re-assignment. My above comment applies if you remove the `PASSWORD="${PASSWORD@Q}"` line.

Comment: what is the output of echo $PASSWORD and what error you got?

Comment: did you try to escape special char with: `ESCAPED_PASSWORD=$(printf "%q" "$PASSWORD")` and `--password="$ESCAPED_PASSWORD"`?

Comment: @Lety, PASSWORD will contain quotes after the "`@Q`" assignment. Nothing usable from there: mysqldump will receive a quoted string as password (it will consider the quotes as part of the password).

Comment: @Lety : i get this  $'passwordwp*\r'
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'duser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect. With ESCAPED_PASSWORD=$(printf "%q" "$PASSWORD")
 echo $ESCAPED_PASSWORD
 mysqldump --no-tablespaces --host=$HOST --user=$USER --password="$ESCAPED_PASSWORD" $DB | gzip > $FILE

Comment: @Bruno : i get this with : passwordwp*
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'duser'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" when trying to connect. With this code echo $PASSWORD
 mysqldump --no-tablespaces --host=$HOST --user=$USER --password="$PASSWORD" $DB | gzip > $FILE

Comment: @Delirium6: You have 2 issues here: 1) your file seems to be in DOS format (`\r` in PASSWORD), and 2) as I said above, you **do not want** quotes within the `PASSWORD` variable.

Comment: Yes my csv is in DOS FOrmat, UTF-8 CR LF Windows, it's not ok ?

Comment: You have to remove the `\r` from the PASSWORD variable. The easiest would be to use `dos2unix` on your csv file, if you don't have any other constraint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247510/discussion-between-delirium6-and-bruno).

Comment: Rather than storing your DB connection credentials in a plain-text .csv file, you might have a look into using `mysql_config_editor`.   This enables you to store authentication credentials in an encrypted login path file named .mylogin.cnf.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-config-editor.html

Comment: It ok with unix file, thank to @Bruno.

Comment: For @j_b, i know, but the problem is that i'm on a managed server on Ionos, so for each databases, i have a different host, login, dbname and password. And the goal is to save all this databases, and i don't want to create 30 mylogin.cnf for my 30 databases. Or if you have any idea to store this in 1 mylogin.cnf